# How to get variable value on express that's on another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-handling

How to get variable value, if the variable was inside app.use

chatbot.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express.Router();


app.use(['/chat', '/chatbot'], (req, res, next) => {
const bot = req.query.bot;
const client = req.query.client;
const text = req.query.text;
const json = require('./json/chatbot')
        
const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json.result[req.query.text].reply));

  console.log(result)
  res.json({'reply': result});
});

module.exports = app;
```

json/chatbot.js:

```js
const botFile = require('../chatbot');
const bot = botFile.app.bot;


const data1 = ["Hi!", "Yo!", "Wassup", `Hello ${client}`]
const rep1 = data1[Math.round(Math.random() * data1.length)]

const json = {
        "result": {
"hi": {
    "reply": rep1,
    "id": 0
},
"hello": {
    "reply": rep1,
    "id": 0
},
"sup": {
    "reply": rep1,
    "id": 0
},
"yo": {
    "reply": rep1 ,
    "id": 0
},
"who are you": {
    "reply": `I'am ${bot}`,
    "id": 1
}
}}

module.exports = json;
```

USED URL:

[https://api.domain.repl.co/api/v1/chat?client=ClientTEST&bot=Chat+Bot&text=who+are+you](https://stackoverflow.com)

It should replied

```json
{"reply": "I'am Chat Bot"}
```

But instead, it replied

```json
{"reply": "I'am undefined"}
```

There's no error in console

Comment: what is the value of "json" after your require on line 9?

Comment: const bot = botFile.app.bot; // This is probably undefined

Comment: if i do
const bot = require('../chatbot') it will become app.use(['/chat', '/chatbot'], ...

Comment: but if i do const { bot } = require('../chatbot'), it will become undefined too

Comment: You have a circular dependency here. You can't require both files from each other without a build tool like webpack to resolve the conflict for you.

Comment: It worked if i put the json at same file, but it will become trash, because as you know. It was Chat Bot, so i need to use so many text, Lin on it, so i decided to put it on json/chatbot.js, and jt become like that

Comment: also, app.bot really is undefined in your code

Comment: Idk how to do that.......... See my name? JsNewbie

Comment: I know. That's why I'm explaining it to you.

Comment: what is bot supposed to be?

Comment: Since when did i have app.bot .....

Comment: bot supposed to be req.query.bot a.k.a 'Chat Bot'

Comment: exactly. const bot = botFile.app.bot; ... "who are you": {
    "reply": `I'am ${bot}`,
    "id": 1
}

Comment: You can see i have it on chatbot.js

Comment: {"reply": "I'am undefined"}

Comment: const bot = req.query.bot; This is not on app. This is a variable inside the callback function

Comment: Yeahh??? Thats th error

Comment: I know, that's why I'am asking, how get it out from the app?

Comment: You can try exporting a function instead of the json

Comment: So i can take it to another file

Comment: I'll try a quick answer for you. One sec

Comment: https://api.kingdomdeveloper.repl.co/api/v1/chat?bot=Chat+bot&text=who+are+you / https://replit.com/@kingdomdeveloper/api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

chatbot.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express.Router();
const getBot = require('./getBot.js')


app.use(['/chat', '/chatbot'], (req, res, next) => {
const bot = req.query.bot;
const client = req.query.client;
const text = req.query.text;

const json= getBot(client, bot);

const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json.result[req.query.text].reply));

  console.log(result)
  res.json({'reply': result});
});

module.exports = app;
```

getBot.js

```
function getBot(client, bot){
  const data1 = ["Hi!", "Yo!", "Wassup", `Hello ${client}`]
  const rep1 = data1[Math.round(Math.random() * data1.length)]
  
  return {
          "result": {
  "hi": {
      "reply": rep1,
      "id": 0
  },
  "hello": {
      "reply": rep1,
      "id": 0
  },
  "sup": {
      "reply": rep1,
      "id": 0
  },
  "yo": {
      "reply": rep1 ,
      "id": 0
  },
  "who are you": {
      "reply": `I'am ${bot}`,
      "id": 1
  }
  }}

}

module.exports = getBot;
```

Comment: You're very welcome